# efficienty count the elements in the list

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list:

```
color_list = [    ['black', 'maroon', 'maroon', 'maroon', 'maroon']
['purple', 'black', 'maroon', 'maroon', 'maroon']
['maroon', 'purple', 'maroon', 'teal', 'teal']
['maroon', 'maroon', 'purple', 'maroon', 'maroon']
['teal', 'olive', 'teal', 'maroon', 'maroon']
    ....
 ]
```

Now, I want to count the following:

How many times maroon and black occurred together

How many times purple and black occurred together

How many times maroon and purple occurred together.

and so on..
The colors in color_list comes from a predefined colors.
i.e assume that i have a list of colors ['red','green','teal'....]
and I want to basically find the counts by that red and green occur together "n" times in the color_list together.. red and teal occurs together "m" times..
and so on..

and then.. the next step is to find how many times red, green and blue .. (taking 3 at a time)...

what is the best way to implement this in python?

Comment: I take it that a list with 4 "maroons" and one "black" (like the first element of `color_list`) counts as "one time that black and maroon occur together".

Comment: @Lattyware: So I tried a simple list traversing thing.. maintaining a nested dictionary and the nesting is depending on the number of pairs I am counting.. so I will have something like d["red"]["green"] will give me a number.. but then a different method for keeping track of 3 things.. and hten another method to keep track of 4 things.. so i am going thru list again and again.. this doesnt seem very efficient

Comment: @Lattyware: yes being in a same list twice count as two.. (and not one)

Comment: So then `['black', 'black', 'maroon', 'maroon', 'maroon']` is two coincidences?  This is a rather complicated rule: for two given colors, find all pairs within the set, where a given element in the set may only be counted in one pair.  Is that the rule you want?

Comment: You should really avoid using unclear language such as "occured together". For color A and B, do they occur Min(occurences_A, occurences_B) times together in a list? So the total is the sum of this minimum over all lists? For example, if we have a list [red, red, red, black, black, green, blue, blue], red, black and green occur together 1 time, because 1 is Min(3,2,1)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use collections.Counter:

```
color_list = [                                        
['black', 'maroon', 'maroon', 'maroon', 'maroon']  ,   
['purple', 'black', 'maroon', 'maroon', 'maroon']  ,   
['maroon', 'purple', 'maroon', 'teal', 'teal']     ,   
['maroon', 'maroon', 'purple', 'maroon', 'maroon'] ,   
['teal', 'olive', 'teal', 'maroon', 'maroon']         
]                                                     

from collections import Counter

cnt = [Counter(x) for x in color_list]

for x, y in [('black', 'maroon'), ('teal', 'olive')]:
    print x, y, sum(min(c[x], c[y]) for c in cnt)
```

Comment: +1 - This is the better solution where you need two pairs to count as two occurrences.

Comment: Note that Counter was introduced in version 2.7

Answer (score 3):

Presuming that you take any number of occurrences in a sublist to mean one 'together':

```
color_sets = [set(sublist) for sublist in color_list]
looking_for = {"maroon", "black"}
sum(looking_for <= sublist for sublist in sublist)
```

This works by making your lists into sets, then checking if `looking_for` is a subset of the sets, summing the result (as `True` counts as `1` as an integer).

## Edit:

Just seen your comment saying you do want the number of occurrences to matter. If that's the case, then the simple adaptation of what I had is:

```
sum(min(sublist.count(item) for item in looking_for) for sublist in color_list)
```

However, as `list.count()` is used so much, this won't be very efficent for larger `looking_for`s.

Comment: I'm not a python expert, but are you sure `['black', 'black', 'maroon', 'maroon', 'maroon']` wouldn't count as six coincides in your algo?

Comment: @flies I don't believe so, why do you think that it would?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is very similar to [Association Rule Mining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning). You should look at: http://orange.biolab.si/doc/ofb/assoc.htm .

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're really just looking for every color pair combination that can be made from any given list.  I may be off but if that is your goal, it's a simple problem.  You just need to get the unique items in the set and sum the length of the list - 1.  This is a standard solution to finding pairs where order is not important.  If you start at the left most element in say a list of 4, index 0.  There are 3 items to its right it can be paired with.  Move to index 1, we've already counted the pair with index 0 so there are 2 items to its right it can be paired with, and so on.  The simple way to do this in Python is just

```
sum(xrange(0, len(set(colors))-1))
```

If you have specific colors you need to find pairs of within you arbitrary list, it's similarly simple:

```
sum(xrange(0, len(set(colors) & set(chosen_colors))-1))
```

p.s. `set` instersection kicks ass

Comment: since `['black', 'black', 'maroon', 'maroon', 'maroon']` counts as two  black/maroon pairs, the goal is not just to find every combination, but to weigh the combinations you find in a particular way.

Comment: @flies fair enough, that wasn't clear when I wrote the answer.  My first couple of sentences are a disclaimer as to my interpretation of the problem at the time.